How to resolve #include errors
Doubt regarding c
I tried to print "Hello World" but then found this error. I went through numerous videos on YouTube where they ask you to install MinGW and change the compiler's path but even there the steps for doing the same differ from the steps my system allows me to execute.

You've tagged this C and appear to be working with Hello world.c but the error refers to iostream which is C++. The fact that you have a folder called C and C++ files suggests some confusion – it's better to keep them entirely separate.

Remove space in file name and check your compiler with simplr hello.c

You shouldn't be using #include <iostream> in a C project. You should use #include <stdio.h>.

You seem to be using #include <iostream> which is the Standard Input / Output Streams Library for C++.
In C the standard library we use is #include <stdio.h>. The "Hello, world!" program in C is as follows
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}

Also it's better to use a simpler filename without spaces, eg., hello_world.c/hello.c
Finally you seem to be missing the compiler, please install MSVC from Visual Studio or Clang or MinGW to compile the program.

If Print "Hello World!."
 #include <stdio.h> //* this is header-File*
 
   int main(){
 
  printf("Hello World!.");
  
  return 0;
}

Saved file .c extention i.e Hello.c
gdb-online-compiler' go to run code.

How is this an answer? What was the problem? And why void main() rather than int main(void)?
